# WPF SDK DownLoad (For offline Usage)

Tags: wpf

Is there SDK available to download for wpf, as I wanto read that SDK when I don't have internet. Any idea about it, from where can I download SDK for WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is part of Visual studio, you don't need an SDK.

If you want to learn WPF, trying buying a book (an online book as well)

if you want to use it and get help, I think installing MSDN locally will do it.

Comment: I have download SDK for silverlight, that is why I think there might be SDK for the WPF As well.

Comment: Mean there is no separate SDK for WPF?

Comment: nope, it comes with visual studio (2008) if you have earlier version you might need an add-on, but it's old staff...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the *API*!? This should be included in the MSDN Library which you can download from [**here**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7BBE5EDA-5062-4EBB-83C7-D3C5FF92A373&displaylang=en). However, the library is several GB...

Comment: I know MSDN is in GB that is why I am asking is there any sdk available only for WPF, just like the SilverLight SDK ?